# Symfony2 - reset envirnonment based on PHPUnit configuration

Tags: testing, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to set up two specific PHPUnit test environments for Symfony2.

I am using Ant to run PHPUnit, so when I run the two commands below I would expect the following results:

```
ant test
```

Runs the test suite using MySQL databse. (matching staging and production envs)

```
ant ramdisk
```

Runs the test suite using a SQLite ramdisk. (super fast!)

I can figure out how to set up the MySQL & SQLite for PHPUnit individually, quite easily.

How do I get PHPUnit to specify a particular environment to use?

Our base class for testing sets up the environment, but I cannot figure out how to get a argument passed into here from PHPUnit so that I can conditionally set the environment.

I have tried a different bootstrap for ramdisk, but since the base test class sets the environment I could not make much progress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this.

PHPUnit can pass variables through to Symfony: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables